# Alternative to PiCloud with the same convenience

Tags: python, scheduling

Does anyone have an idea for a good alternative for PiCloud?
I want to run Python scrapers. Everything is working fine and the environment is set up scraping into Amazon RDS.

The last 2 days PiCloud is having issues and my scrapers stop as external requests to HTML sites timeout.

I look for a reliable alternative.
That has the same amazing convenience as PiCloud to schedule Python Code.

Comment: I work at PiCloud. Could you file a support ticket to let us know more details about why your scrapers are timing out?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com/) -- for web scrapers, it should be just as good.  Less so for large-scale number crunching right now.

Answer (score 0):

Engineyard is one alternative: https://www.engineyard.com/

There's also AWS/EC2, here's some discussion on that [Amazon EC2 vs PiCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653060/amazon-ec2-vs-picloud)